# js code not running on node but it properly works on html

Tags: javascript, nodes

[image]

trying to run this code on node but comes up with this error

```
var weight = 350;
var time = 7;
var age = 77;
var gender = "male";
 if (weight > 300 && time < 6 && age > 17 && gender === "male") {
   alert("Come to our tryout!");
 }
 else {
   alert("Come to our cookout!");
 }
```

Comment: Nothing there can possibly cause a CORS error - is there any other code?

Comment: Alternative for node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/alert-node

Comment: @godot I think this is a duplicate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function alert is implement by the browser window.

Nodejs does not implement alert.

You can use console.log() to output to the screen.

Like this

```
const weight = 350;
const time = 7;
const age = 77;
const gender = "male";
 if (weight > 300 && time < 6 && age > 17 && gender === "male") {
   console.log("Come to our tryout!");
 }
 else {
   console.log ("Come to our cookout!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't have the `alert` function. You would have to use `console.log`. Additionally, I think this (`[![enter image description here][3]][3]`) part is not valid javascript. If you make the adjustments, then your code would look something like

```
var weight = 350;
var time = 7;
var age = 77;
var gender = "male";
if (weight > 300 && time < 6 && age > 17 && gender === "male") {
   console.log("Come to our tryout!");
}
else {
   console.log("Come to our cookout!");
}
```

For further reading, see the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the Node.js you don't have a window object, so you also do not have an alert function which is supposed to open a pop-up with the provided message.

So if you want the code to run in a specific environment, you could go for environment specific code; So in Node you could use the `console.log` method for instance (i'd strongly recommend using this in the browser too)

About the window object you can read more on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert